PC randomly crashes and does not post, VGA LED on - GPU and Motherboard replaced
My friend's PC has started to crash randomly, when gaming but occasionally also when idling. When trying to reboot after a crash, it does not POST and the VGA led remains lit. After waiting for some time (no hard data on how long exactly) it manages to boot normally again, and runs fine until the next crash.
We have replaced the GPU and the mainboard, but the issue still occurs. Any idea on what might be wrong, and what to try next?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
